# Resize modal popup base on content with Modal Forms module in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript

I use the [Modal Forms](http://drupal.org/project/modal_forms) module to show the popup for the website and it worked well with fixed data (from we have several sizes for modal forms : small, medium, large) but for the dynamic data (The content will be changed for each time loading the popup) it is displayed outside the popup and i don't know how to fix that.

Does anyone have the same problem and how to fix that?